# Bootstrap Notification cant correctly create it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create like this Bootstrap Notification , im try to create this but i cant correctly do it, 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN5kG.png)

**html**

```
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">today</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">all</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">missed</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Front Desk</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Calander Alerts</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Expense reported</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have tried with any code? if yes then put here...

Comment: im using this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

Comment: Your code is working fine.. All you have to do is apply CSS styling.

Comment: @AbhishekKumbhani sir do you know any site or example like this

Comment: What exactly you want? I don't understand. your code is working fine.

Comment: @Dixit sir look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN5kG.png , im try to create this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have created plunker please check this helps you.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lwa5CUDjZDWL2lPBmULX?p=preview

Comment: @Jhone please check this link which I have created plunker, I think what you need this can do.

Comment: Thank you sir, now i can do it my style